# NodeList returns XML with null in JAVA

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to parse a XML in following steps but XML returned is Null

Step 1: I get following string in XML in response

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <saml1p:Response InResponseTo="123456789" IssueInstant="2020-12-03T02:11:31.675Z" MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" ResponseID="_b7dfe0c3d6d5288e03089058e9c47640" xmlns:saml1p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:protocol">
            <saml1p:Status>
                <saml1p:StatusCode Value="saml1p:Success" />
            </saml1p:Status>
            <saml1:Assertion AssertionID="_8d6e176b1c2b4b5822bdcd001c1453f9" IssueInstant="2020-12-03T02:11:31.675Z" Issuer="localhost" MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" xmlns:saml1="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion">
                <saml1:Conditions NotBefore="2020-12-03T02:11:31.675Z" NotOnOrAfter="2020-12-03T02:12:01.675Z">
                    <saml1:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
                        <saml1:Audience>https://URL</saml1:Audience>
                    </saml1:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
                </saml1:Conditions>
                <saml1:AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationInstant="2020-12-03T00:55:05.315Z" AuthenticationMethod="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:am:password">
                    <saml1:Subject>
                        <saml1:NameIdentifier>xxx</saml1:NameIdentifier>
                        <saml1:SubjectConfirmation>
                            <saml1:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:artifact</saml1:ConfirmationMethod>
                        </saml1:SubjectConfirmation>
                    </saml1:Subject>
                </saml1:AuthenticationStatement>
                <saml1:AttributeStatement>
                    <saml1:Subject>
                        <saml1:NameIdentifier>xxx</saml1:NameIdentifier>
                        <saml1:SubjectConfirmation>
                            <saml1:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:artifact</saml1:ConfirmationMethod>
                        </saml1:SubjectConfirmation>
                    </saml1:Subject>
                    <saml1:Attribute AttributeName="displayLastName" AttributeNamespace="http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/">
                        <saml1:AttributeValue>xxx</saml1:AttributeValue>
                    </saml1:Attribute>
                    <saml1:Attribute AttributeName="displayFirstName" AttributeNamespace="http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/">
                        <saml1:AttributeValue>xxx</saml1:AttributeValue>
                    </saml1:Attribute>
                    <saml1:Attribute AttributeName="mail" AttributeNamespace="http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/">
                        <saml1:AttributeValue>xxx@gmail.com</saml1:AttributeValue>
                    </saml1:Attribute>
                    <saml1:Attribute AttributeName="sAMAccountName" AttributeNamespace="http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/">
                        <saml1:AttributeValue>xxx</saml1:AttributeValue>
                    </saml1:Attribute>
                    <saml1:Attribute AttributeName="displayName" AttributeNamespace="http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/">
                        <saml1:AttributeValue>xxx</saml1:AttributeValue>
                    </saml1:Attribute>
                    <saml1:Attribute AttributeName="givenName" AttributeNamespace="http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/">
                        <saml1:AttributeValue>xxx</saml1:AttributeValue>
                    </saml1:Attribute>
                    <saml1:Attribute AttributeName="description" AttributeNamespace="http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/">
                        <saml1:AttributeValue>DEPRECATED</saml1:AttributeValue>
                    </saml1:Attribute>
                    <saml1:Attribute AttributeName="distinguishedName" AttributeNamespace="http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/">
                        <saml1:AttributeValue>xxx</saml1:AttributeValue>
                    </saml1:Attribute>
                    <saml1:Attribute AttributeName="employeeID" AttributeNamespace="http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/">
                        <saml1:AttributeValue>xxx</saml1:AttributeValue>
                    </saml1:Attribute>
                    <saml1:Attribute AttributeName="cn" AttributeNamespace="http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/">
                        <saml1:AttributeValue>xxx</saml1:AttributeValue>
                    </saml1:Attribute>
                    <saml1:Attribute AttributeName="pepRole1" AttributeNamespace="http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/">
                        <saml1:AttributeValue>xxx</saml1:AttributeValue>
                    </saml1:Attribute>
                    <saml1:Attribute AttributeName="memberOf" AttributeNamespace="http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/">
 
                    </saml1:Attribute>
                    <saml1:Attribute AttributeName="sn" AttributeNamespace="http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/">
                        <saml1:AttributeValue>xxx</saml1:AttributeValue>
                    </saml1:Attribute>
                    <saml1:Attribute AttributeName="department" AttributeNamespace="http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/">
                        <saml1:AttributeValue>xxx</saml1:AttributeValue>
                    </saml1:Attribute>
                    <saml1:Attribute AttributeName="group" AttributeNamespace="http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/">
                        <saml1:AttributeValue>DEPRECATED</saml1:AttributeValue>
                    </saml1:Attribute>
                </saml1:AttributeStatement>
            </saml1:Assertion>
        </saml1p:Response>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Step 2: I use document builder to build XML

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource iSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlResponse));
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(iSource);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

Step 3: I'm getting node and modifying attribute value of saml1p:Response, after executing below code XML returned is null

```
//Begin Issue seems to be in this block of code
NodeList samlResponse = doc.getElementsByTagName("saml1p:Response");
Element samlResponse = (Element) samlResponses.item(0);
samlResponse.setAttribute("InResponseTo", "_" + samlResponse.getAttribute("InResponseTo"));
//End Issue seems to be in this block of code
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
transformer.transform(source, new StreamResult(output));
```

Above code returns null, any ideas why this issue occurs?

Interesting thing this code works in production but not in our test environment.

Comment: This code appears to work fine.  I'm using OpenJDK 11.  Can you share more information?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. What information would you like to know?

Comment: We are using below JRE: 
java version "1.7.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_261-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.261-b07, mixed mode)

Comment: That Java version hasn't been supported for 5+ years without Oracle support.  The best I can tell you is that it's working fine as a small test program in OpenJDK 11.  If it's working on other machines then I'd focus on the version.  If this is running in a server environment (i.e. Tomcat, WebLogic, etc.) then, again, I'd make sure the version is the same.

Comment: Thanks again, version on both production and test environments is same. Yes we do have Oracle support. I'll wait to see if others have any recommendations or check any setup.